# How can I keep streusel topping from getting soggy?

Tags: texture, casserole, food-transport

I make this [Sweet potato casserole](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/15633/gourmet-sweet-potato-classic/?internalSource=hub%20recipe&referringContentType=search%20results&clickId=cardslot%202) for Thanksgiving, it has a streusel like topping. Usually I can bake this at the destination, but this year I need to bake at home and take. I have a baking dish that has a heat resistant plastic cover and an insulated carrier. I know that the topping will get soggy if it is tightly covered after baking. How can this be avoided?

Comment: How long are you traveling, and how long will it be between when you take it out of the oven and when you serve it?

Comment: Actual car time about 15 minutes. Not sure how long it will be till it hits the table, maybe around an hour.

Comment: Are you planning to keep the casserole warm, reheat it or just serve at whatever temperature it has at dinner time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want to serve the casserole hot and the streusel crispy, keep the casserole and the streusel **separate** until almost serving time.

This means you will have to bake the streusel on a cookie sheet until crisp and ready, then let them cool uncovered and transport them in a separate container.

Your casserole base contains eggs, so it must be baked. You want to avoid a "skin" or "crust", so cover with foil at least part of the time or even the whole 30 minutes. (Depends a bit on how wet the mash is.)

Depending on the logistics at the destination, either keep your casserole warm in your carrier or pop it in the microwave for a bit to gently(!) reheat it.

The right time to put the streusel on top of the base is a short while before serving - long enough that the hot mash can warm them up and that they can get a tiny bit soft at the bottom (more authentic!) while staying crisp on top. A few minutes should suffice, but a quarter of an hour would still be fine. But keep the casserole uncovered.